# LDAP Server System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, ldap

I keep having this message when running the code below. I want to read the values from a LDAP server and put them in an array. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

By the way I know what an index out of range means but I don't know why it is happening here. The problem is not with the array. Any clue?
Thanks for your help.

```
    static void ReadValues()
    {

        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher()
        {
            PageSize = 2000
        };

        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");

        SearchResult result;
        SearchResultCollection resultColl = search.FindAll();

        Membre_CU[] mCU = new Membre_CU[resultColl.Count];


        for (int counter = 0; counter < resultColl.Count; counter++)
        {

            result = resultColl[counter];

            //if (result.Properties.Contains("cn"))
            mCU[counter].cn = result.Properties["cn"][0].ToString();
            mCU[counter].description = result.Properties["description"][0].ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(mCU[counter].cn);
            Console.WriteLine(mCU[counter].description);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

Comment: you should use the debugger and try setting the counter to `<=` vs `<`  have you even tried stepping thru the code..?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Some people didn't have the attribute I was looking for.